# How can I work round the fact that java ByteBuffer size cannot change

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer

I read binary data from a file in chunk into a ByteBuffer and then process the data in the ByteBuffer. I like using ByteBuffer because I can make use of the order() method to correctly read out Shorts and Integers.

At a later time I have to write new/modified data to the file. The idea was to use a ByteBuffer again and make use of its put methods. However I don't know easily know the size required in advance, I could work it out but it would mean parsing the data twice. Alternatively I could use ByteArrayOutputStream but then I have to write methods to deal with writing BigEndian/LittleEndian integers ectera.

What do you recommend, is there a third option ?

Comment: Wrap a DataOutputStream around a ByteArrayOutputStream.

Comment: Hmm, good idea except you cant specifying byte order when writing ints only does BigEndian

Comment: You could use `Integer.reverseBytes` to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two (other) approaches:

- If the problem is that you can't predict the file size in advanced, then don't.  Instead use `File.length()` or `Files.size(Path)` to find the file size.
- If you can process the file in chunks, then read a chunk, process it, and write it to a new file.  Depending on your processing, you may even be able to update the `ByteBuffer` in-place.  If not, then (presumably) the size of an output chunk is proportional to the size of an input chunk.

---

What do I recommend?

I'm not prepared to recommend anything without more details of the problem you are trying to solve; i.e. the nature of the processing.

Comment: Im writing data to an existing file (Audio metadata in fact ), the problem is that I don't know how much space each piece of metadata will require when written until I read it and calculate its size.

Answer (score 0):

If yours use case guarantees that the file won't change during the processing, then it *might be* a good idea to use `MappedByteBuffer`.